# Java - Kelvin to Fahrenheit conversion method

Tags: java, formula, temperature

So I'm currently working on a pretty simple program. What it does is convert either Fahrenheit or Celsius to Kelvin, and then depending on what the user requests (f or c) that kelvin value is converted and returned as either Celsius or Fahrenheit.

My Celsius conversion seems to work just fine, but Fahrenheit is a different story. Our professor says our output must match the given example 100%, and when I give a Celsius value and request Celsius back, it always returns the value I originally put in.

However, I got this when converting 95 Celsius to Fahrenheit: 203.28800000000007
The value I was supposed to get was: 203.0
Furthermore, when I put in 50 Fahrenheit and requested it to return Fahrenheit, I got this: 32.0.

I'll post the class that contains all my conversion methods, but could anyone help me out with where I might be going wrong? It looks to me like based on my formula, it's simply returning the part of the formula that adds/subtracts 32. I've tried alternative formats of the formula, but nothing seems to be working.

```
public class Temperature 

{

// Instance variable

   private double degreesKelvin; // degrees in Kelvin

// Constructor method: initialize degreesKelvin to zero

   public Temperature() 
   {
      degreesKelvin = 0;
   }

// Convert and save degreesCelius in the Kelvin scale

   public void setCelsius(double degreesCelsius) 
   {
      degreesKelvin = degreesCelsius + 273.16;
   }

// Convert degreesKelvin to Celsius and return the value

   public double getCelsius() 
   {
      double c = degreesKelvin - 273.16;
      return c;
   }

// Convert and save degreesFahrenheit in the Kelvin scale

   public void setFahrenheit(double degreesFahrenheit) 
   {
      degreesKelvin = (5/9 * (degreesFahrenheit - 32) + 273);
   }

// Convert degreesKelvin to Fahrenheit and return the value

   public double getFahrenheit() 
   {
      double f = (((degreesKelvin - 273) * 9/5) + 32);
      return f;
   }

}
```

Thanks for any assistance, I tried looking for solutions to this issue, but nothing seems to work for me so far.

Comment: 203.28800000000007 can be scaled to return 203.2 and You have no method to put Fahrenheit and return Fahrenheit !

Comment: Use 5.0 / 9 instead of 5 / 9 and 9.0 / 5 instead of 9 / 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Watch out for integer division, the result of 2 integers (when divided) yields an integer:

```
5/9 = 0
9/5 = 1
```

To fix this, cast 1 of them to a floating type, like:

```
5d/9 //or 5.0/9
```

And likewise with

```
9d/5 //or 9.0/5
```

Comment: Ah, worked perfect, thank you! My professor hadn't taught us that yet. Some of the numbers are still off my a tiny margin, but I think I might be able to round them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is happening because while storing you are adding 273.16 to the degree celsius. The extra .16 introduces this error. 
for 95 degree celsiun

degreeKelvin = 273.16+95

now while returning it becomes

5/9*(273.16+95-273) +32 == 5/9(95.16)+32 == 203.2

while

5/9*(273+95-273) + 32 == 203

Comment: Unfortunately, the .16 is mandatory according to the conversion formula. Although the answer for that one conversion just happened to be 203.0, other examples we were given could contain many numbers after the decimal point. The fact that I wasn't getting exactly 203.0 was simply sending a signal that my formulas were wrong somewhere.